# The subset of X formed by non-decreasing functions is closed

Tags: general-topology

I am currently stuck on a topology problem. Here is the problem:
If (X,d) is the space of continuous and bounded real functions with the sup norm, then the subset of X formed by bounded, continuous, non-decreasing real functions is closed.
I don't know how to prove this. Any help will be appreciated.
Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Rough idea:

Let $Y \subset X$ be the subset of all nondecreasing continuous function.

Let $g_n \in Y$ and $g_n \to g$ in sup norm. Then $g$ is continuous (Why?). To show that $g\in Y$ we need to check that $g$ is nondecreasing. Assume the contrary, assume there are $x<y$ so that $g(x) > g(y)$. Then $g_n(x) > g_n(y)$ for $n$ large (Can you justify that?). But this is impossible as $g_n \in Y$. Thus $g$ is also nondecreasing and so $g\in Y$.

Thus $Y$ is closed.